# Filter NSArray objects for key ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have a `NSArray` filled with `json` objects in the following format:

```
@"name" : @"a.smith"
@"age" : @"23"
@"badge" : @"red"

@"name" : @"f.wren"
@"age" : @"31"
@"badge" : @"blue"

@"name" : @"j.liby"
@"age" : @"19"
@"badge" : @"red"
```

I am trying to create a new `NSMutableArray` filled with only the objects who's `badge = @"red"`

`seg` is my existing `NSArray` containing all of the objects. These are being used to populate a custom `tableViewCell`:

```
NSArray *seg = [selections objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSMutableArray *newBadgeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
if ([[[seg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"badge"] isEqualToString:@"red"])  {
    [newBadgeArray insertObject:seg atIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

I'm getting the below error and am not sure why

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'

Comment: Probably you get `indexPath.row == 4` whereas `seg` have only 3 items. Make sure you don't return larger numbers for table delegate

Comment: Yes. That may be the case. I guess you are using the array as a datasource in table view. Please check the no of rows in your table view. It should be equal to your array's length.

Comment: What is the no of rows in your table view? Is it hard coded?

Comment: You told that 'seg' is the array containing all the objects. Then what is 'selections' array?

Comment: i am using the above method in my delegate method to set numberOfRows .                                                                                                  if ([selections count]>0) {
        
        NSArray *seg = [selections objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];                                    return [seg count];             this is the original method which works, but now i want it to only contain objects with valueForKey @"badge" : @"red"

Comment: selections is the original NSMutableArray which is populated in my ViewDidLoad from NSDictionary json objects

Comment: One more doubt. 'selections' is your parent array and 'seg' is the child array. Am I correct? You have a array within array structure?

Comment: Because the error actually describes clearly that there are only 4 elements in the array and you are trying to access the 5th (index: 4) element. Hence, the crash.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet from your viewDidLoad where you populate the 'selections' array.

Comment: selections array is everything within my json, seg array is creating each time for setting the subcell number of rows, which each sub cell section is its own section of selections array (selections objectAtIndex:index path.row)  hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you try "NSArray *seg = [selections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];"

Comment: Is it working with indexPath.section?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to filter your array to show in a tableview then you must filter it outside of tableview's datasource and delegate methods.

```
@interface YourVC()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *newBadgeArray;
@end

@implementation YourVC
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //...

    NSArray *seg = //initialize your array 
    this.newBadgeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if ([[[seg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"badge"] isEqualToString:@"red"])  {
        [newBadgeArray insertObject:seg atIndex:indexPath.row];  
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    retirn newBadgeArray.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the filtered array in viewDidLoad itself. For simplicity, use fast enumeration.

```
NSMutableArray *newBadgeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSArray *seg in selections) {
    NSLog(@"seg array: %@", seg);

    [seg enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
        if ([[[seg objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"badge"] isEqualToString:@"red"])  {
            [newBadgeArray addObject:seg];
        }
    }];
}
```